# Rewrite rule with exception

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Here is my directory structure

main site:-

```
www.magentosite.com
```

Wordpress site:-

```
www.magentosite.com/wordpresssite
```

And Here is my htaccess rule for redirect. If User goes to wordpress site then they will  redirect to magentoSite.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^WordpresSITE/
RewriteRule .? http://www.MagentoSITE.com/ [L]
```

**PROBLEM**

Above should work as it is but I want to put if user goes to admin side of wordpress then yes they should not redirect. In short `www.magentosite.com/wordpresssite/wp-admin/...` should not redirect.

Comment: you are right it did not worked on other browser

Comment: @Prix do you have any solution on this?

Comment: I have put / now but no luck...:(

Comment: Where is the `.htaccess` that you're currently editing with that rule at ? Do you also have an `.htaccess` on the WordPress folder?

Comment: yes it is in the wordpress folder

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49126/discussion-between-rajat-modi-and-prix)

Comment: when I put on magento's htaccess it gives infinite loop error I'm also editing my question.

Comment: nope at the end of the htaccess I have updated my question

Comment: I want to redirect this www.magentosite.com/wordpresssite to www.magentosite.com and not redirect on this case www.magentosite.com/wordpresssite/wp-admin/... hope that makes sense so I have to put some rule on the magento's htaccess or on the wordpress's htaccess

Comment: That makes more sense now ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code should go inside the `.htaccess` on the WordPress folder:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpresssite/(wp-login\.php|wp-admin) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.MagentoSITE.com/ [R=302,L]
```

Basically what I am doing is if the URL start with:

```
www.magentosite.com/wordpresssite/wp-login.php
```

Or starts with:

```
www.magentosite.com/wordpresssite/wp-admin
```

It **should not redirect**, if it **doesn't then it redirects**.

Comment: nope it does not worked I have put this and it redirects in both cases. 

1) www.magentosite.com/wordpresssite/ and 
2).www.magentosite.com/wordpresssite/wp-admin

Comment: You've placed it on the `.htaccess` inside the WordPress folder correct? And you also used a browser that is not cached correct? And I forgot to a `/` on the `wp-login` check the rule again.

Comment: I added again deleted the cache and then force refreshed browser but still it redirects. :(

Comment: do you also have an `.htaccess` inside the `wp-admin` folder?

Comment: can you come on the chat room so we can discuss very promptly

Comment: @RajatModi I don't use the chat, see my update, this is the exact code I use to reproduce and test your case which works just fine perhaps your may be missing something that is important.

Comment: :) nice to hear that.